# Clear-Site-Data: "cache" header is not clearing the disk cache (Tested in Chrome 114.x)

Tags: xmlhttprequest, browser-cache, cache-control, response-headers, clear-site-data

When user hits on login button the login request (ajax request to https://example.com/login) returning site following headers (**`Clear-Site-Data: "cache"`**) but still getting cached response from the subsequent request.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sat, 17 Jun 2023 08:27:31 GMT
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 433
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self';base-uri 'self';block-all-mixed-content;font-src 'self' https: data:;form-action 'self';frame-ancestors 'self';img-src 'self' data:;object-src 'none';script-src 'self';script-src-attr 'none';style-src 'self' https: 'unsafe-inline';upgrade-insecure-requests
Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy: require-corp
Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy: same-origin
Cross-Origin-Resource-Policy: same-origin
X-DNS-Prefetch-Control: off
Expect-CT: max-age=0
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15552000; includeSubDomains
Referrer-Policy: no-referrer
X-XSS-Protection: 0
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Clear-Site-Data: "cache"
ETag: W/"1b1-qSdkeWSPPEfc+zO3en4Zo/KFDzg"
```

also I can see below error in my console

`Clear-Site-Data header on https://example.com/login: The request's credentials mode prohibits modifying cookies and other local data.`

But seems like chrome has support for this header according to MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Clear-Site-Data

Why the cache is not getting cleared ?

Am I doing anything incorrectly or is it a bug ?

*Note: this is cross origin request*